# iFrame doesn't take up space in div

Tags: css, iframe

How can I get a margin to separate the iFrame from the 'p' tag?

I'm using an iFrame (vimeo embed) in a div. The div contains the iFrame, h2, p and h6 tags.

I want the video to appear on the left side of the div, and the text on the right.

To accomplish this, I apply float:left to the iframe.

Upon page load, everything looks fine except for the margin between the iFrame and the text divs.

Live Example here:
http://mammola.info/HomePageTest/media/Testing.html

The 'p' text is shoved up directly along the edge of the iFrame - the margin property of the 'p' exists behind the iframe (same with any border). I can not get a margin or border separate the 'p' and the iFrame

When I inspect the elements, it appears that the iframe is not even showing up in normal positioning. The 'p' tag spans the full width of the page.

How can I get a margin to separate the iFrame from the 'p' tag?

jsFiddle here:
http://jsfiddle.net/JrzS6/1/

```
    <style> .portfolio-item {
    text-align:center;
}
#iframecontainer {
}
iframe {
    FLOAT:left;
}
.portfolio-item p {
    text-align:left;
    margin:40px;
}
</style>

<div class="portfolio-item">
    <iframe width=500 height=281 src="//player.vimeo.com/video/46011352" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>
     <h2> Title </h2>

    <p>Stuff about the vidoe in the description. Stuff about the vidoe in the description. Stuff about the vidoe in the description. Stuff about the vidoe in the description.</p>
     <h6> Creator | editor | Cinematographer </h6>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about adding a `padding` style to the iframe element

http://jsfiddle.net/FJdPT/1/

```
<style> 
.portfolio-item {
    text-align:center;
}

#iframecontainer {
}

iframe {
    FLOAT:left;
    padding: 20px; <!-- Added this -->
}

.portfolio-item p {
    text-align:left;
    margin:40px;
}

</style>
```

Comment: That seemed to do it! Seems like a silly problem, now... I coulda sworn I tried that, but I guess not. 

Thanks a lot!